# loader in jquerymobile application

Tags: jquery-mobile

I know that in jquerymobile application, if we use pagebeforeshow page event, all the events inside that execute multiple times. I find the solution i.e: to unbind the event when hiding the page and bind the event when show the page. But what about the code, which is not inside any function or which has to execute every time the page is visited without any event (like click, tap, bind, focus etc.).
**Code:**

```
    $(document).on( 'pagebeforeshow', '#profile', function(event){

    //call to fetch user data
    //first part        

             var invocationData6 = {
                        adapter : 'registerUser',
                        procedure : 'fetchUserProfileData',
                        parameters : [profileId]
                };

                WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData6, {
                    onSuccess : fetchSuccess,
                    onFailure : fetchFailure,
                });


            function fetchSuccess(result){
                 $.mobile.utils.hideWaitBox();
                var invocationResult = result.invocationResult;
                var array1 = invocationResult.array;

            }

            function fetchFailure(result){
                $.mobile.utils.hideWaitBox();
                WL.Logger.error('Fetch Unsuccessful');
            }

//second part
             $(document).undelegate('#updBtn1', 'click').delegate('#updBtn1', 'click', function() {
                var newAge = $("#updAge").val();
                var newPhone = $("#updPhone").val();
                var newSmoker = $("#flip-9").val();
                $.mobile.utils.showWaitBox("e", "Wait! Updating your Info...");
                        var invocationData7 = {
                                adapter : 'registerUser',
                                procedure : 'updateRegisterData',
                                parameters : [profileId, newAge, newPhone, newSmoker]
                        };

                        WL.Client.invokeProcedure(invocationData7, {
                            onSuccess : update1Success,
                            onFailure : update1Failure,
                        });


                    function update1Success(result){
                         $.mobile.utils.hideWaitBox();

                    }

                    function update1Failure(result){
                         $.mobile.utils.hideWaitBox();

                    }

            });



     });
```

As you can see in the code that the first part is not enclosed inside anything so that it cannot be bind or unbind to prevent it from executing multiple times in pagebeforeshow page event. But the second part can easily be prevented from this problem by using delegate and undelegate events. 
So, how to prevent the first part from executing multiple times. I cannot enclose it as it has to be executed when the page is changed using $.mobile.changePage.

Comment: Hey, a little confused trying to understand. Basically you don't want "WL.Client.invokeProcedure" to execute on every page change. Correct?

Comment: @Dan No.. What I am trying to say that is that, if I changepage, firstpart executes one time, then if I go back and come again, firstpart executes two times and so on. How to avoid this. As you can see that the second part can be avoided from this problem by using delegate and undelegate events.

Comment: I see. See if this helps with your issue. I have had a simpler problem and this helped. http://api.jquery.com/one/

Comment: Also make sure your .on code is not inside another trigger that may be causing multiple executions.

Comment: @Dan, I think you still can't understand what the actual problem is. The code written inside the first part is not bind to any event (like click, tap, on, etc), so How I use .one or any other event to prevent the problem.

Comment: both of those pieces of code are bound to the pagebeforeshow event. ".on('pagebeforeshow'"

Comment: bind click and any other events to `pageinit`. For functions that you want to executed whenever a page is viewed, use `pageshow` or `pagebeforeshow`.

Comment: @Omar I used pagebeforeshow because I wanted the first part to execute every time the page is shown. But as you can see that In the first part http adapter is invoked and then it connects to my domain where php code is written which fetch results from database and those results are to be printed on the page. So, if I went to required page first time, results are shown as desired, but when I visit to same page second time, results are shown two times and so on which is not desired.